# Order records of occurrences "in array"

Tags: mysql, sql

basically i want to

```
Select * from x 
JOIN y
on x.id = y.x_id
where y.tag_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) order by [the amount of hits of y.tag_id]
```

so

say y can be:

```
id | x_id | tag_id
1 | 55 | 2
2 | 55 | 3
3 | 66 | 1
```

I want to make the record x.id = 55 to sort above x.id = 66. 55 has 2 hits (2, and 3) whereas 66 only has one hit

Answer (score 1):

You can find count of hits per x_id in a subquery, join it with the X table and sort the result by calculated count.

```
Select * from x 
JOIN y
on x.id = y.x_id
inner join (
    select x_id, count(*) cnt
    from y
    group x_id
) t on x.id = t.x_id
where y.tag_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
order by t.cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the `x_id` that matches the passed `tag_id` and use it in `Order by`

```
SELECT *
FROM   x
       JOIN y
         ON x.id = y.x_id
       JOIN (SELECT x_id,
                    Count(*) hit_cnt
             FROM   y
             WHERE  y.tag_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
             GROUP  BY x_id) ct
         ON ct.x_id = y.x_id
ORDER  BY hit_cnt DESC
```

It is important to apply the filter while counting because we need to count the `x_id's` for the matched `tag_id's`